# Animate drawing from image file

Tags: android, animation

Is there a way to animate the drawing of an image (from PNG) in a custom view?

I have an image of a circle that I would like to be drawn within a custom view. It would have to appear to be drawn in a clockwise direction.

Thanks

Comment: Have you checked out the android.view.animation package? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/package-summary.html

Comment: I do know of the package but are you suggesting an AlphaAnimation for this? Would really help if you could show how to use this for a circular image in a custom view (never really tried animating before).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want something to look drawn, not just a current image manipulated/transformed, I would look at Frame Animation.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/view-animation.html#frame-animation

Comment: Hmm... I did want to avoid loading multiple images to keep the size down. So would really love to know if this could be done with available Canvas drawing "magic"?

Comment: I've gone ahead and dropped the animation. Didn't want to have to load 4 images (one for each quadrant) just to show a circle :). Thanks for your response though.

Comment: Well I did go with this finally. But apparently for some reason Google decided to not allow developers a proper way to determine when Frame animations are finished (read requires a hack around) which makes this a pain...